# Why there is no images drow when I turn on web page?

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, draw

I want to draw images on web page from array, but there is no images on web site. There is array of 6 images which I want to display on web site, also I want to make them move up, and I want to appear them randomly on x axis, but there is no images on web site

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext("2d"); 

var description = [ "cerveny", "fialovy", "cierny", "zeleny", "modry", "zlty"];

var pictures = new Array(5);

function initialize(){
    pictures[0] = new Image(50, 50);
    pictures[0].src = "cerveny_novy.png";
    pictures[1] = new Image(50,50);
    pictures[1].src = "fialovy_novy.png";
    pictures[2] = new Image(50,50);
    pictures[2].src = "cierny.png";
    pictures[3] = new Image(50,50);
    pictures[3].src = "zeleny_novy.png";
    pictures[4] = new Image(50,50);
    pictures[4].src = "modry_novy.png";
    pictures[5] = new Image(50,50);
    pictures[5].src = "novy_zlty.png";
}

initialize();

for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    c.drawImage(pictures[i], 50, 400, 600, 200);
}
```

Comment: I think I did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to bind `onload` handler

```js
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");  

var description = new Array ("cerveny", "fialovy", "cierny", "zeleny", "modry", "zlty");

var img=[
  "https://picsum.photos/id/231/50/50",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/232/50/50",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/233/50/50",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/234/50/50",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/235/50/50",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/237/50/50",
]

function initialize(){
  return img.map(p=>new Image(50, 50)).map((p,i)=>{
    p.src = img[i];
    p.onload = () => c.drawImage(p, Math.random()*200, 20*i, 50, 50);
    return p;
  });
  
}

var pictures= initialize();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=250 height=150></canvas>
```

Comment: it works, thanks. And how can I add background behind this images?

Comment: add at the begining in separate way one image (with full canvas size) and in it onload handler call `initialize()`

Comment: this is not working:
function initialize(){
 c.drawImage(pozadie, 0, 0);
  pictures = img.map(p=>new Image(50, 50)).map((p,i)=>{
    p.src = img[i];
    p.onload = () => {
      c.drawImage(p, 200*i, 400, 200, 200);
    }
  });
}

Comment: and also, I want the images moving up

Answer (score 0):

That is because you're trying to draw the images onto the canvas using drawImage() without making sure that those have finished loading.
First create a temporary variable which will reference the image you want to draw

```
var image = new Image();
```

Second assign an event listener to it, which will monitor loading of the image and a callback function which will actually draw the image.

```
image.onload = function() {
  c.drawImage(image, 100, 100);
}
```

Finally change the src property of the temporary image to the desired image to start loading

```
image.src=images[0].src;
```

Comment: can you please write it to me code? because I cant make it working

Answer (score 0):

It seems you aren't waiting for images to load before drawing them.

Try drawing in onLoad:

```
pictures[i].onload = function(){ 
  c.drawImage(pictures[i], 50, 50);
};
pictures[i].src = "novy_zlty.png";
```

You might want to create a drawing function and call it in onload of each element of pictures array.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage